# What are all the payment channels implementations?

Tags: lightning-network, sidechains, micropaymentchannels

I know the [Lightning Network](https://lightning.network/) (which [Electrum](https://electrum.org/) wallet experimentally supports) is an implementation of a payment channel, but [*Mastering Bitcoin*](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook#chapters) (2<sup>nd</sup> ed.) ch. 12, § "[Routed Payment Channels (Lightning Network)](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch12.asciidoc#routed-payment-channels-lightning-network)" says:

> The Lightning Network [was first described by Joseph Poon and Thadeus Dryja in February 2015](https://lightning.network/lightning-network-paper.pdf), building on the concept of payment channels as proposed and elaborated upon by many others.

What are the "many others"? Is the [Elements Project](https://elementsproject.org/)'s "pegged sidechains" "building on the concept of payment channels" too?

Answer (score 2):

The Lightning Network is much more than an implementation of a payment channel. It is a peer-to-peer network whose core purpose is to route payment through a set of multiple payment channels.

Then, i think you are confused with regard to the quote: "many others" here refers to
*persons* not projects. See [this wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Payment_channels) for mentions of some of them.

Finally, as you mention Elements is defining [sidechains](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sidechains) (a peer-to-peer network whose core purpose is to update a block chain that is somehow pegged to Bitcoin) which are not "building on the concept of payment channels".
However, payment channels may (not yet deployed) be a good abstraction for interconnecting sidechains with Bitcoin or in-between them.